# Double For loop

Tags: javascript, html, loops, svg

Well I asked this question earlier and made a right mess of it, simply;

I have two nested for loops:

```
//example x co-ords
var v_circle_collection = [550, 450, 350, 450, 1000, 1450, 1900, 2350, 2200, 2200, 2800, 2700, 2600, 2700, 3250, 3050];

//example x co-ords of circle collection
var circleCollection = [450, 900, 1350, 1800, 2250, 2700, 3150];

for (var i = 0; i < v_circle_collection.length; i++) {

    for (var n = 0; n < circleCollection.length; n++) {

        //i only need to go through CircleCollection 7 times. but this nested for loop does the 16*7 sum.
        if (v_circle_collection[i] > circleCollection[n]) {
            //do the stuff i need to do
        }
    }
}
```

the First loop will go round 7 times whilst the other loop goes round 16 times doing a 7*16 sum. What i need the first for loop for is to access all of the values in `circleCollection` as there are only 7 in that array however because of the next for loop then going around 16 times it interferes with it.

I only need to go through `circleCollection` 7 times, is there a way i can do this? Is using nested for loops the like this the wrong way?

what i really need is some sort of count that will only go to 0-6 instead of using another for loop.

JS FIDDLE - https://jsfiddle.net/oomw8snq/1/

[image]

this is the goal i'm trying obtain
[image]

[image]

if I hard code it it works how ever because there can be an arbitrary amount of circles created this is not viable:

[image]

the code: the for loop doesn't really matter in this case it just needs one to access the values inside the circles objects.

```
for(var i=0; i < v_circle_collection.length; i++) 
{
 if(v_circle_collection[0].getX() > circleCollection[0].getX())
    {

        v_circle_collection[0].setX(v_circle_collection[0].getX()+5);
    } 

    if(v_circle_collection[2].getX() < circleCollection[0].getX())
    {

        v_circle_collection[2].setX(v_circle_collection[2].getX()-5);
    }        


    /*Y's*/
    if(v_circle_collection[1].getY() > circleCollection[0].getY())
    {

        v_circle_collection[1].setY(v_circle_collection[1].getY()+4);
    }        

    if(v_circle_collection[3].getY() < circleCollection[0].getY())
    {

        v_circle_collection[3].setY(v_circle_collection[3].getY()-4);
    }    

}
```

Comment: What's objCollection?

Comment: just an array of SVG circle elements in which i can get the X's and Y's values.

Comment: in what way does it *interfere* with the values? If you know that it should only be looping through 6 times, why can you not just say `for(var i=0; i < 7; i++) { ... }`?

Comment: Ah well i say 6 for because thats the test data it's based upon the size of circleCollection's length which can be anything.

Comment: Could you please provide us with the target goal, instead of what you got after thinking, to catch the real problem

Comment: you want to loop 7 times because of the length of circleCollections right? Does that mean you need to compare only with the first 7 values ?

Comment: "s some sort of count that will only go to 0-6 instead of using another for loop." seems like if you only need one for loop.. using circleColleciton but not sure if you are planning to compare the values in the same position of circleCollection and v_circle_ollection

Comment: Yes well the first value in circleCollection is compared against the first four values in the v_circle_collection. the second value in the circleCollection is then compared against the 5th value in v_circle collection, and so on, i've added some new images to give a better context, i'm really sorry im making this confusing!

Comment: From where you deduced that the 1st element should be compared with the first 4 elements, and the 2nd one with the 5th element, ...etc

Comment: seems like he is comparing the four elements because of the second picture. You need a different structure to know which little bubbles belong to the circle collections..

Comment: @rahpuser exactly, that's why I'm asking him about that, he has more details :)

Comment: Right so i'm guessing that v_circle_collection shouldnt cotain EVERYTHING in one massive array but rather split them up into their corresponding counter parts i.e [array[4],array[1],array[1],array[1]], like that? Also you're correct in guessing that! Sorry i wasn't clear enough!

Comment: also just a little thank you to everyone who has helped!

Comment: I guess there is an euclidean distance factor here, not only `>` or `<`

Comment: Seems like each big circle represent an Object right and each little circle connected to that object represent the attributes this object has ? Could you please share with us the code that generate the pictures ? we can propose a structure or solution in base of that.

Comment: You're comnpletely on the ball there! Each image you see is an entire object it's RDFa data. the Big circle the the thing you're trying to define I.E a person, the second circle is that things property I.E Hair and the smallest circle is the property Value i.E black. The code used to generate the images are simply native JS code with a getters and setters for the x's and y's of each circle:                       is how a new circle object is created var newObj = new RDFaObject(node.nodeTypeOf()[o], node.nodePredicates()[o], node.nodeValues()[o], "_:"+o);

Comment: RDFaObject is not native JS so far as I know. Are you using some library? Or is RDFaObject the custom object ?

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to switch loops..

```
 for(var i =0; i < v_circle_collection.length; i++)
     {

           for(var n=0; n < objCollection.length; n++){
```

Comment: that will still do the same sum of 16*7, essentially what i need is a count from 0-6 within that first for loop in your suggestion. the issue i'm facing is that circleCollection only has 0-6 vaules whereas soit does 0*16, *1*16, 2*16 etc......

Comment: Please can you describe the problem better.. I think I can help you but now I am confused.. 

ok.. lets see: 
objCollection.length = 7
v_circle_collection.length = 16;
and what about this: small_circle_collection ?

Comment: sorry that wasn't meant to be in there. Erm.. well the first loopes goes from 0-6 correct, i need to used 0,1,2,3,4,5,6 to access all of the vaules within objCollection as there are 7 values in there starting @ 0. However the second collection of circle objects v_circle_collection has 16 values in it so i needed another loop to access all of them as well.  so what i need is a counter starting from 0 counting to 6 instead of the that first for loop so i can do objCollection[count] or something.

Comment: I've added a JS fiddle.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to go through the nested loop to do the comparison you are doing.

currently you are looping 112 times total. the following code will make you loop ONLY when there are elements in "circleCollection" smaller than the current "v_circle_collection" element. T

hat should make you loop 57 times instead.

```
//example x co-ords
var v_circle_collection = [550, 450, 350, 450, 1000, 1450, 1900, 2350, 2200, 2200, 2800, 2700, 2600, 2700, 3250, 3050];

//example x co-ords of circle collection
var circleCollection = [450, 900, 1350, 1800, 2250, 2700, 3150];

function filter(arr, criteria) {
  return arr.filter(function(obj) {
       return criteria > obj;
  });
}

var x = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < v_circle_collection.length; i++) {
    var filtred = filter(circleCollection,v_circle_collection[i]);
    if(filtred.length > 0) { 
        //Found circleCollection that were lower than v_circle_collection do your code here        
    }

    for (var n = 0; n < filtred.length; n++) {
        x++;
        //do the stuff i need to do only on the circleCollection that were smaller than the v_circle_collection
    }
}
alert(x);//total of time i looped (original code was 112)
```

Comment: it should also make you loop only on the Smaller elements. and not the whole list

Comment: to add an extra layer of complexity those example arrays are the base values of the circles x position to actually obtain that value it needs to be done like circleCollection[i].getX() and circle collection and v_circle_collection are both different sizes.

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid the `for()` loop in linear arrays:

```
var v_circle_collection = [550, 450, 350, 450, 1000, 1450, 1900, 2350, 2200, 2200, 2800, 2700, 2600, 2700, 3250, 3050];
var circleCollection = [450, 900, 1350, 1800, 2250, 2700, 3150];
v_circle_collection.forEach(function(v_c_c){
    circleCollection.forEach(function(cc){
        if(v_c_c > cc) {
            ...
        }
    });
});
```

If you need a `svg + data`, consider the [d3.js](http://d3js.org/) library